# Comms between uplinks on same vSwitch on ESX

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, esxi, vmware-server, switching

I'm driving myself crazy thinking this should work, but it's just not!

I have the below setup in ESX.

[image: vS]

The vubuntu VM has an IP of 10.0.10.99/24 as do the VMkernel interfaces (I have two as a backup). I have a router connected to vmnic0 which has the IP 10.0.10.1 and I can ping from the vubuntu VM all these interfaces. Good so far.

The issue: On vmnic5, I have an OpenWRT (MR12 wifi ap) router which I was going to use as a wifi entry point into my management network. This OpenWRT router has the IP 10.0.10.6 . If this is plugged into the router on vmnic0 I can ping it from the VM fine, if I plug it directly into vmnic5 (as above) there are no comms...

So I guess the question is:

Do packets get switched between uplinks in the same switch?

If not, this is the reason my experiment doesn't work, and I can semi deal with it. If they **do** get switched usually, what is broken in my setup that I dont see any comms from vmnic5 when sniffing the interface using the vubuntu VM?

Comment: So it appears if I set "Network failover detection" to "Beacon only" on vSwitch0 NIC Teaming setting I get pings between the vubuntu VM, VMkernel and the wifiAP. What I still don't get is comms between hosts attached to the two vmnics!

Comment: Do you have to use NIC teaming in the first place? I don't know ESX, but otherwise this would be the expected result with a "team" of non-equal links...